# How to pass search params from server client?

Tags: next.js

I use the new next13 app dir, I want to pass search params from the (page.tsx) as server client and using it inside get request API route (/api/shipments/[shipmentsId]/route.ts).

example of my url:

```js
http://localhost:3000/?search=abc
```

my current method:

```js
export async function GET(req: Request, context) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const searchTerm = searchParams.get('search') as string;
...
}
```

but it gives me a null value, how to get the value correctly?

Comment: It's working for me, the example you have given.